# SQL- Creating an Inner JOIN for Two Columns inside Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am attempting to work out a practice problem from my book. 
The problem goes like this:

Find all the vendors who have invoices that have not been paid yet. 
(Hint: the invoice_total will be different than the payment_total).

Rewrite the above query in a total of 3 ways: 
Using equijoins, using INNER JOIN and using NATURAL JOIN.

I completed the first step by doing,

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR_ID
FROM INVOICES
WHERE Invoice_Total != payment_total;
```

However, when I try to do the inner joins, I keep getting errors. 
Both Invoice_Total and Payment_Total are columns inside of the same "INVOICES" table.

How would I be able to show the discrepancies whilst pulling the vendor ID's?

[This is a picture of the practice database that I am working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oOz7.jpg)

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.'

Comment: Look for a column in the invoice table that relates it to a vendor. Something like `vendor_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems silly to inner join a table to itself to solve this particular problem (there are plenty of good reasons to self-join, but this isn't one of them), but I suppose from a "practice problem" standpoint it's reasonable.

I would think here it would be best to pre-aggregate the `invoices` before the join to cut down on the processing time (unless there is an index in place to help the join):

```
SELECT t1.vendor_id
FROM (SELECT vendor_id, sum(invoice_total) sum_invoice_total FROM INVOICES GROUP BY vendor_id) t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT vendor_id, sum(payment_total) sum_payment_total FROM INVOICES GROUP BY vendor_id) t2
        ON t1.vendor_id = t2.vendor_id
WHERE
    t1.sum_invoice_total != t2.sum_payment_total
```

There is a chance this could break down though if it's possible for a vendor to overpay for an invoice. Consider:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| invoice_id | vendor_id | invoice_total | payment_total |
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|          1 | a         |            10 |            20 |
|          2 | a         |            10 |             0 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Without pre-aggregating (again this makes no sense, but it will work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.vendor_id
FROM invoices t1
    INNER JOIN invoices t2
        ON t1.invoice_id = t2.invoice_id
WHERE
    t1.invoice_total != t2.payment_total
```

This is nearly identical to your original query, but adds in a superfluous inner join. I'm just guessing at your primary key as `invoice_id` here. Edit as needed.

Comment: You are a wizard bro, I spent two hours googling what I thought was a basic question, because this is a basic SQL course. I suppose this question is as asinine as you say it is.

Comment: Also, using a Natural join on itself is actually impossible due to the nature of a Natural right?

Comment: Well... If it works it would join on every column which would be strange. But the result would be correct.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id
FROM invoices 
   NATURAL JOIN invoices 
WHERE
    invoice_total != payment_total;



I tried to modify the statement that you had made in order to make the Natural Join Statement. I think I might be misconstruing something here.

Comment: You have to alias your tables. `from invoices as t1 natural join invoices t2 Where t1.invooce_total !=t2.payment_total` sorry for typos. On phone.

Comment: Alright, I fixed a typo and then ran the statement but it pulled an error. Then I took out the AS modifiers and then ran it. Now it is throwing a " column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier".

"Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
           or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier."

Comment: Perhaps because it is trying to natural join on all columns (being the same table) this won't work. You could, as a ridiculous workaround, natural join in a subquery, and then do the WHERE clause outside of it. But... that is bringing this to a whole new level of crazy.